# VS 2008 Debugging: CrystalReports Cache

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I'm debugging issues from some CrystalReports documents through Visual Studio '08 (please, kill me now). In addition to the CrystalReports .NET libraries containing some of the worst interfaces I've ever seen, the web viewer for CrystalReports seems to behave strangely while debugging. Unlike regular .aspx pages, the CrystalReports documents don't seem to be live-updated while the debugger is running.  A page refresh does not always retrieve the updated document.
I can only imagine that VS is caching the documents themselves somehow. But I can't seem to figure out when it decides to dump the cache and retrieve the updated CrystalReports document. It's inconsistent at best. Sometimes my changes are reflected on a page refresh, sometimes not. Sometimes it won't even dump the cache when I do a full site rebuild.
I need to be able to make incremental changes and see them updated, as I haven't found any easier way of debugging CrystalReports. Does any one have some insight on how this caching works? My debugging is going extremely slowly because of this problem.
Tokenistic code (this would, obviously, be in an aspx page):

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer runat="server" ID="CRV1" ReportSourceID="CRS1" />
<CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CRS1" runat="server">
            <report filename="CrystalReport.rpt" /> 
</CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

thanks, guys

Comment: I've found that closing the project in VS and reopening it, doing another build seems to work.  The latest changes to the Report document is always reflected after that. However, this is an EXTREMELY time-consuming method of debugging.  Is there really no other way?  Does anyone else have this same issue? I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If your report is pulling back old data then 9 times out of 10 you will want to find the "Save Data with Report" option and uncheck it (this is a property/option that's saved with the report).

In the full version of Crystal this is on the "File" menu.  I suspect in the VS version you can find it in the report options.  I bet this is the cache problem.